# Can I use pandas to create a biased sample?

Tags: pandas, sample

My code uses a column called booking status that is 1 for yes and 0 for no (there are multiple other columns that information will be pulled from dependant on the booking status) - there are lots more no than yes so I would like to take a sample with all the yes and the same amount of no.

When I use

```
samp = rslt_df.sample(n=298, random_state=1, weights='bookingstatus')
```

I get the error:

> ValueError: Fewer non-zero entries in p than size

Is there a way to do this sample this way?

Comment: How many rows are in your dataframe rslt_df? If you have fewer than 298 rows in your dataframe, then you may be exceeding the limit of rows to sample from. You can fix this by setting replace=False.

Answer (score 1):

If our entire dataset looks like this:

```
print(df)                                                                               
   c1  c2
0   1   1
1   0   2
2   0   3
3   0   4
4   0   5
5   0   6
6   0   7
7   1   8
8   0   9
9   0  10
```

We may decide to sample from it using the [`DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) function. By default, this function will sample without replacement. Meaning, you'll receive an error by specifying a number of observations larger than the number of observations in your initial dataset:

```
df.sample(20)
ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'
```

In your situation, the ValueError comes from the `weights` parameter:

```
df.sample(3,weights='c1')
ValueError: Fewer non-zero entries in p than size
```

To paraphrase the [DataFrame.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) docs, using the **c1** column as our weights parameter implies that rows with a larger value in the **c1** column are more likely to be sampled. Specifically, the `sample` function will not pick values from this column that are zero. We can fix this error using either one of the following methods.

---

**Method 1:** Set the `replace` parameter to be true:

```
m1 = df.sample(3,weights='c1', replace=True)
print(m1)                                                                               
   c1  c2
0   1   1
7   1   8
0   1   1
```

**Method 2:** Make sure the `n` parameter is equal to or less than the number of 1s in the **c1** column:

```
m2 = df.sample(2,weights='c1')
print(m2)                                                                               
   c1  c2
7   1   8
0   1   1
```

If you decide to use this method, you won't really be sampling. You're really just filtering out any rows where the value of **c1** is 0.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful. Therefore if I am looking for a way to take an even amount of rows that c1=1 and c1=0 then I need to find a different way to do this.

Comment: You could do something like this: (df[df['c1'] == 1].sample(2)).append(df[df['c1'] == 0].sample(2))

Answer (score 0):

I was able to this in the end, here is how I did it:

```
bookingstatus_count = df.bookingstatus.value_counts()
print('Class 0:', bookingstatus_count[0])
print('Class 1:', bookingstatus_count[1])
print('Proportion:', round(bookingstatus_count[0] / bookingstatus_count[1], 2), ': 1')
# Class count
count_class_0, count_class_1 = df.bookingstatus.value_counts()

# Divide by class
df_class_0 = df[df['bookingstatus'] == 0]

df_class_0_under = df_class_0.sample(count_class_1)
df_test_under = pd.concat([f_class_0_under, df_class_1], axis=0)
df_class_1 = df[df['bookingstatus'] == 1]
```

based on this https://www.kaggle.com/rafjaa/resampling-strategies-for-imbalanced-datasets

Thanks everyone